# Modern examples of Multiplayer Network Architecture

Tags: architecture, networking, multiplayer, client-server

There's a lot of documentation on Multiplayer Network Models for games from the early 2000's (Quake3, Unreal, Counter-Strike, Source Engine) which go through concepts such as client-server architecture, latency compensation methods, prediction and delta-compression of game states.

However, as these models were rapidly improving (as you can tell from Doom to Quake1 to Quake3 and so on) I am led to believe that a lot of improvements probably happened after these as well. Therefore I am looking for documentation on a contemporary Multiplayer Network Model such as League of Legends or similar. It seems to me that LoL has an excellent model given how responsive and accurate it feels compared to a lot of alternatives.

Which is the latest well documented client-server Network Model for a twitch gameplay multiplayer game? Are the Source and Unreal engines continuously improved upon? Does CS:GO use the Source Engine of old?

Comment: This question is too broad, you talk about some of the parts of networking implementations, perhaps you should ask about one of them (e.g. client-server architecture, latency compensation methods, prediction and delta-compression of game states.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this but this would be an interesting read: [Source Multiplayer Networking](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking)

Comment: @ShaunWild That's a good answer. But that's one of the documentations I've been reading up on. Basically what I'm wondering is if there's a more contemporary documentation of the exact same subject for a modern game such as League of Legends or similar.

Comment: I can't check because I'm in work but there are some interesting blogs on this website iirc. [Riot Games Engineering](https://engineering.riotgames.com/)

Comment: As of early 2017 I think Overwatch is pretty much state of the art. Tim Ford gave an excellent talk at GDC 2017.